# Should arbitrarily-sized arrays be stored under a single key in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to persist a list of similarly-typed data on the client using localStorage.  Each piece of data is a high-score and other information about a game session.  Accessing by key isn't necessary here; I'm more likely going to iterate the list and display either the full list or sections of it.

It would look like there are two choices for me:

1. Stringify the whole array somehow and store them under the same key (perhaps "gamedata" or something similar).
2. Store each piece of data under a separate key (perhaps using a timestamp).

Here are the downsides for each choice:

1. Adding one item into the list (the most common operation) will require reading the whole list, adding the item, and writing the data back to localStorage.  I'd expect about a hundred items in the list, but there might be outliers that play the game more often, and I don't want it to lag for them.  The data might get corrupted if the user closes the page or shuts down their computer while writing to localStorage, thereby losing all their game data.  It also doesn't really feel right to read the whole thing and write most of it back untouched.
2. I have to iterate the whole localStorage to find all my data.  Doesn't feel like the right use of an associative array.  Also, this method would probably be less efficient in terms of storage space due to the storage of keys.

Which method is the preferred method for storing my data?

Comment: My _gut_ says that the first one would be faster/easier, but it's hard to say.  You might get a lot of opinion-based answers, but you could always use a tool like https://jsperf.com/ to try to assess if one is truly faster/more efficient.  I know that speed isn't the _only_ consideration, but it might be a useful/helpful metric to have.

Comment: The other thing to consider here would be race conditions where one tab reads in from local storage, a second tab modifies the local storage, then the first tab modifies the (now stale) array and saves it back again. This probably isn't a realistic issue, but it is worth thinking about.

Comment: @JosiahDaniels I didn't think about that!  But for a normal user, I don't see why he'd play my game simultaneously on multiple tabs.